# IE is taking response of controller as a file

Tags: java, javascript, spring, iframe

Following is my code where i tried to upload files from my code,code is working properly in chrome and mozilla but not working for IE.For IE when controller returns int (which shows if file is uploaded successfully or not) it gives browser as file and because of this it asks to open or save file and i f i open that file in notepad it shows that int which is 1 or 0 depending upon the result, i dont know why it is taking it as file.please help me out.

```
// controller side code
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
//@produces(text/html) //tried this as well but didnt change the result. 
public @ResponseBody int upload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
@RequestPart("dataFile") MultipartFile file
){ code to write file on mentioned directory which returns 1 on success and 0 on failure}
```

// code in javascript which submits iframe(which submits form) to controller

```
<html>

<script language="Javascript">
function fileUpload(form, action_url, div_id) {
    // Create the iframe...
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");

    // Add to document...
    form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
    window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";

    iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");

    // Add event...
    var eventHandler = function () {

            if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
            else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

            // Message from server...
            if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
                content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
            } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
                content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
            } else if (iframeId.document) {
                content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
            }

            document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;

            // Del the iframe...
            setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 250);
        }

    if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
    if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

    // Set properties of form...
    form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
    form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");

    // Submit the form...
    form.submit();

    document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Uploading...";
}
</script>

//html code 
<!-- index.php could be any script server-side for receive uploads. -->
<form>
<input type="file" name="dataFile" id="dataFile" /></br>
<input type="button" value="upload"
        onClick="fileUpload(this.form,'upload','uploadShow'); return false;" >
<div id="uploadShow"></div>
</form>

</html>


//code of view resolver
public class AppConfig {

    // Resolve logical view names to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory
    @Bean
    ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1)What is the view resolver that you are using? 2) Could you try explicitly specifying the mime type in your response to txt/html?

Comment: following is my view resolver code                                       public class AppConfig {

 // Resolve logical view names to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory
 @Bean
 ViewResolver viewResolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  return resolver;
 }
 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. I had to setup spring mvc environment first before trying out your code.

I have changed the return type of the controller method from int to String and apparently it works now. Can you give it a try.

```
public @ResponseBody String upload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
@RequestPart("dataFile") MultipartFile file ){ 
    if(file!=null){
        return "1";
    }
    return "0";
}
```

Comment: You are the superman !! perfectly working now... do you have any idea why it was not working when it was returning int.

Comment: I am baffled too... I tried with Integer too but that didn't work. Need to check spring code...